# Designing a database tables for the following scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design, c#

I just got following entities Employee, Client and Company. Where Employee and Client have one to many relationship with Company  ie A single employee may be mapped to attend to many companies and same for clients too. How would i design a optimized table for this situation.
I had thought of below

### **Employee:**

Id

Name

CompanyId

but since it is one to many companyid would have to be saved as comma seperated company id's. What do i do in this situation.

Comment: "A single employee may be mapped to attend to many companies" but can a company have more than one employee mapped to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a many-many (aka link or junction) table between the 2

EmployeeCompany

Columns:

- EmployeeID
- CompanyID

Keys:

- Primary key is (EmployeeID, CompanyID)
- Add a unique index (CompanyID, EmployeeID)
- EmployeeID has FK to Employeetable
- CompanyID has FK to Company table

**Do not** store a CSV in a column: this is bad practice, can't enforce data integrity, can't search it efficiently, has no meaning etc

Note: A column called "ID" is very ambiguous so this is one case where you prefix with the table name

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a `company` can be "attended to" by more than one `employee`, and likewise for `client`, you would model like this:

[image: ER Diagram]

So both relations are 'many:many'. As gbn also said, adding "comma separated ids" would be something of a disaster in database design: you would regret it many times over.